# Casting a primitive vs Creating a object of the primitive

Tags: java

I'm not habitual to casting a *primitive* data type to an object. Saw some code like:

```
public static int CompareAges(Person p1, Person p2) {
    Integer age1 = p1.getAge();
    return age1.compareTo(p2.getAge());
}
```

The instantiation of `age1` seemed extraneous, so I tried to write the code as:

```
public static int CompareAges(Person p1, Person p2) {
    return p1.getAge().compareTo(p2.getAge());
}
```

But that raised a compiler error because `p1.getAge()` is a primitive data type `int` and not an `Integer`, which is an object.

Intuitively, I did:

```
public static int CompareAges(Person p1, Person p2) {
    return ((Integer) p1.getAge()).compareTo(p2.getAge());
}
```

and it worked!

The question: What did I miss? Since when did we start **casting primitives as value types**?

Comment: `int` is being unboxed into the `Integer` object as a result of the cast of the assignment.

Comment: @Tunaki: You mean boxed? So, compiler infers that we want to box, when we try to cast an integer?

Comment: @displayName Yes, casting an `int` to an `Integer` is boxing the primitive into the Object.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5: *The compile-time legality of a casting conversion is as follows: [...] An expression of a primitive type may undergo casting conversion to a reference type without error, by boxing conversion.*

Comment: @JBNizet: That fully explains it. Thanks.

Comment: Apart from the casting question, I would encourage you to avoid boxing and unboxing as much as possible, for this integer comparison either use `Integer.compare(p1.getAge(), p2.getAge())` or if your java version doesnt support it copy the implementation which is `return; p1.getAge() < p2.getAge() ? -1 : (p1.getAge() == p2.getAge() ? 0 : 1);`

Comment: Basically what you try to do in your second example is `5.compareTo(6)`. Thats works in languages like ruby because 5 would be an Object. In Java however 5 is a primitive type. As a funny side note: `"Blah".compareTo("blub")` would be fine because "Blah" is a String instance and not a primitiv.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's what happens internally:

```
1. Integer age1 = p1.getAge();
       Integer != int
       Integer = Integer.valueOf(int)
   Integer age1 = Integer.valueOf(p1.getAge());

2. p1.getAge().compareTo(p2.getAge());
       int.compareTo(int)
       ^^^
       // it's just a primitive type, as a result - the compile error

3. ((Integer) p1.getAge()).compareTo(p2.getAge())
       Integer.compareTo(int)
       Integer.compareTo(Integer.valueOf(int))
   ((Integer) p1.getAge()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(p2.getAge()))

4. (Integer) p1.getAge() ---> Integer.valueOf(p1.getAge()) 
       // why so? look at callOfCode's answer
```

But, in my opinion, `((Integer) p1.getAge()).compareTo(p2.getAge())` looks ugly.

I would replace it to

```
p1.getAge() > p2.getAge() ? 1 : (p1.getAge() < p2.getAge() ? -1 : 0)
```

or to

```
Integer.compare(p1.getAge(), p2.getAge()) // java 7+
```

I wouldn't like to do casting in this case.

---

More about "autoboxing/unboxing" you may find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: Revisiting your answer, I see that we could simply return `p1.getAge() - p2.getAge()`. Don't need all the comparisons that you are doing in `p1.getAge() > p2.getAge() ? 1 : (p1.getAge() < p2.getAge() ? -1 : 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

[Each primitive has its own boxing type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

[image]

The Boxing could be implicit (Autoboxing) or explicit like you did it in your code.

`p2.getAge()` is an Example of AutoBoxing or Implicit Boxing. The method `compareTo` takes an Object. As it is a primitive, Java converts it automatically to the correspondent Boxing Object (Integer). You did the explicit Boxing with the cast `(Integer) p1.getAge()`

Comment: @YassinHajaj: No implicit boxing happened really. I tried the second code snippet first but that raised compiler error. That is why I went to third code snippet, and hence this question.

Comment: @displayName `p2.getAge()` is an Example of AutoBoxing or Implicit Boxing. The method `compareTo` takes an Object. As it is a primitive, Java converts it automatically to the correspondent Boxing Object (Integer). You did the explicit Boxing with the cast

Comment: @YassinHajaj: That's what I'm saying... The implicit boxing did not happen! Raised a compiler error.

Comment: @displayName I think this is a misunderstanding. `p1.getAge()` had to be explicitely boxed, that's why if you did not do it, you got an error. The reason for that is because you were calling a method on it. `p2.getAge()` on the contrary had not to be care of, because as a parameter, the autoboxing happened automatically.

Comment: Besides of that, I do not understand the downvotes guys.

Answer (score 3):

Difference between `new Integer(primitive);` and `Integer integer = (Integer)primitive;` Is only on bytecode level. In the first case, new object of Integer class is created in memory. In the second case, `Integer.valueOf(primitive)` is called internally. This is the static method that checks if primitive falls into range of -128 to 127 and if it falls, it returns value from integer cache and no new object is being created. If it not falls into that range, new `Integer` object is instantiated. It is used for efficiency. But such efficiency is unsignificant novadays.

```
int z = 1;
Integer a = (Integer)z;
Integer b = (Integer)z;
//Prints true, since Integer object is retrieved from cache (range of -128 to 127)
System.out.println(a == b);

int w = 999;
Integer c = (Integer)w;
Integer d = (Integer)w;
//Prints false, since 999 is not in cache, new Integer objects are instantiated and they points to different places in memory
System.out.println(c == d);
```

Comment: I don't quite get the -128 to 127 thing. Are you saying that you will not always get the same return type when performing a cast?

Comment: JVM statically instantiates values from -128 to 127 and keeps these values in memory for extra performance as "most commonly used values". That's eliminates the need to instantiate them again and again, since retrieval from cache is faster than instantiation. You will always get the same return type.

Comment: That's something I didn't know before. Thanks. It's useful.

Comment: @displayName You're welcome. Java is so deep. I've updated my answer with code snipped.

Comment: The code snippet makes it clear beyond a shadow of doubt.